# Verifying my understanding of lambda involving return statement

Tags: python

I am sharing my understanding of how below code works. Please verify if it's correct. I did some print statements for my understanding.

```
1    def writer():
2        title = 'Sir'
3        name = (lambda x:title + ' ' + x)
4        print(f"Line 4: {type(name)}")
5        print(f"Line 5: {name}")
6        return name

7    who = writer()
8    print(f"Line 8: {who}")
9    print(f"Line 9: {who('Arthur')}")
```

Output

```
Line 4: <class 'function'>
Line 5: <function writer.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000008FB65E8>
Line 8: <function writer.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000008FB65E8>
Line 9: Sir Arthur
```

Line 6 is returning a function (writer or lambda) which is stored or mapped to "who" variable on Line 7. Now, "who" becomes the lambda expression and when called on Line 9 with "Arthur" as an argument, that becomes the value of "x" in lambda expression of Line 3. And therefore, printed "Sir Arthur".

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first-class objects in Python, whether created by a lambda expression or (as would be preferred here) a `def` statement.

```
def writer():
    title = 'Sir'
    def name(x):
        return title + ' ' + x
    return name

who = writer()
```

The only difference between the above and something like

```
title = 'Sir'

def who2(x):
    return title + ' ' + x
```

is that `who` will *always* use the value `title` had at the time `writer()` returned. The behavior of `who2` can be changed by changing the value of the global variable `who2` at any time. `who` is an example of a *closure*; the function object itself keeps a reference to the value originally assigned to the now out-of-scope local variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Line 6 is returning a function (writer or lambda) which is stored or mapped to "who" variable on Line 7.

Correct, the "value" returned by `writer` is a lambda that takes one argument x and returns a string.

> Now, "who" becomes the lambda expression and when called on Line 9 with "Arthur" as an argument:

Let's carefully run through the evaluation of line 9.

1. When calling `print`, Python first evaluates the arguments, turning the code into a value in memory ... let's evaluate
2. When evaluating an f-string, Python first evaluates the code in brackets in the current context.  In this case, `who('Arthur')` evaluates to `"Sir Arthur"`.
   To be clear, `who('Arthur') --> (lambda x:title + ' ' + x)('Arthur') --> title + ' ' + 'Arthur' --> "Sir Arthur"`
3. Now Python completes the evaluation of the f-string by replacing the expression in brakets with its value. So in this instance, `f"Line 9: {who('Arthur')}"` becomes `"Line 9: Sir Arthur"`
4. Now that Python knows the value of each argument, it can have `print` work its dark magic.

Hope that helps!